# Does this viral video show a man's head explode while inflating a dinghy?

Tags: video

An old viral video (apparently from 2001) shows a man inflating a dinghy by mouth, when a child jumps on, increasing the pressure and causing the man's head to explode in a puff of smoke.

It has been widely seen, including at [9gag](http://9gag.com/gag/aNWjQ4v) and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Auy9SAKvNs).

The commenters on both argue about whether it is fake or real.

Did a man's head explode from inflating a dinghy?

Comment: Warning to commenters: There are plenty of places on the web to *speculate* about this video. This is not one of them. You will need to provide evidence for your claims.

Comment: Precisely. I want something with stronger evidence.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I am glad and very relieved it's fake

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you observe at the top of the [linked youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Auy9SAKvNs) you can see it says "www.theviralfactory.com".

I found their youtube channel [via archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20101222112218/http://theviralfactory.com/) click on "Work" and the "youtube". The video stream won't work, but there is a link to [The Viral Factory channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/Viralfactory). On there you can find [their copy of the linked video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBOoFHuQYTQ).

Quoting the description:

> This was the first clip we ever made, to launch our company. We received 300 emails telling us we were sick bastards for blowing up some poor dudes head. We didn't, it's fake in case you're still wondering.

Comment: Oh boy, youve done some work answering that. However, the first bit would have been just right - if we know the author of the video, and they've said its fake that is good enough. The rest of your answer is [Original Research](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/faq-what-constitutes-original-research)

Comment: @Jamiec - Ok. I'll remove it and walk way. I did consider that if I take a video where somebody dies and I upload it and say it is fake, doesn't make it so. This site has weird standards. Edit: done.